# How to maintain the file reading pointer in code igniter php back and forth between the view?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter, file-upload

I've got a Code Igniter controller which reads the uploaded record file (excel, csv, tsv, xml, etc) and writes each line as a record into the database. The record ID which is the first column in the file should be unique. If it is already present in the database then while reading the file I should throw an alert and depending on the user's response I will override or skip the record and continue with the other records.

But once I throw the alert and reach the view, I loose the control of the controller and I don't know to keep the file pointer ticking so that I can continue to read after receiving the response from the user.

Is there a work around for this or do we have an other alternative method?

Comment: Can you please add a code or something? Adding a bit of what you have will help us understand where you are. `:)` Please [edit] the question to add more info.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider I have a file like this:

```
Roll, Name, Age, Subject
1, Praveen, 25, Cloud Computing
2, Sri Ram, 25, Cloud Computing
3, Dhiwa, 23, Computer Science
4, Vennila, 25, Cloud Computing
5, Arun, 22, Computer Science
```

Being a CSV file, I would read it using PHP's built-in function [`str_getcsv`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php) to read the file, this way:

```
$csv = array_map('str_getcsv', file('data.csv'));
```

I would take the collection of the records' Roll, which is a collection of unique entries, by parsing the array's first value, so that I would get something like:

```
Array (
  1,
  2,
  3,
  4,
  5
)
```

And finally I would assume the database would already have a similar structure like:

```
+--------+------+-----+---------+
| UserId | Name | Age | Subject |
+--------+------+-----+---------+
```

So, now I would use a SQL's `GROUP_CONCAT` function to group all the `UserId`s together and get it as this way:

```
$UserIdsFromDB = get_first_row_value("SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(`UserId`) FROM `Users`");
```

I would get parse it as an array and have the result in `$UserIdsFromDB` this way:

```
Array (
  5,
  17,
  22,
  23,
  55,
  56
  57
)
```

I could easily use a PHP's built-in function [`array_intersect`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) to find those values that are repeated, which gives me:

```
Array (
  5
)
```

And using a simple AJAX call, I would ask if I need to replace the `5` User or all the users, this way:

```
get_user_name(5)                  // Gets the name of the user with ID 5.
count($Array_Intersect_Result)    // Gets the number of matching users.
```

I hope this would take you to a level of understanding. Let me know how it goes.